# Is there a way to make an iOS Simulator always enrolled in FaceID?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I keep having to go to the Menu->Hardware->Face ID/Touch ID->Enrolled and select each day. I just want my simulators to stay Enrolled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. Please do file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com.